# storing theme current value in the localStorage using angular and material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a theme with 2 options (say dark and light) which works perfectly fine. But what i want to achieve is when i select the dark theme and i want to store that dark value in the localStorage. I have a Angular with Material theme. See my below code (This is where the theme buttons comes):

Template code:

```
<li>
    <label class="theme-option-check">
        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="light" [(ngModel)]="AppConfig.theme" />
        <span class="theme-option-item bg-color-page">
            <span class="overlay">
                <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
            </span>
            <span>Regular</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <label class="theme-option-check">
        <input type="radio" name="theme" value="dark" [(ngModel)]="AppConfig.theme" />
        <span class="theme-option-item bg-color-dark">
            <span class="overlay">
                <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
            </span>
            <span>Dark</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Apart from this i am managing the config of the application here in the config.ts file. See code below:

```
function makeAppConfig() {
  const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  const AppConfig = {
    user: 'User',
    year,
    layoutBoxed: false,               // true, false
    navCollapsed: false,              // true, false
    navBehind: true,                 // true, false
    fixedHeader: true,                // true, false
    sidebarWidth: 'small',           // small, middle, large
    theme: 'light',                   // light, gray, dark
    colorOption: '32',                // 11,12,13,14,15,16; 21,22,23,24,25,26; 31,32,33,34,35,36
    AutoCloseMobileNav: true,         // true, false. Automatically close sidenav on route change (Mobile only)

    isLoadingResults: false
  };

  return AppConfig;
}

export const APPCONFIG = makeAppConfig();
```

In app.component.ts file i have added this code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.AppConfig = APPCONFIG;
    if (APPCONFIG.theme === 'light') {
      this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('light-theme');
    } else {
      this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('dark-theme');
    }
    console.log(this.currentTheme);
  }
```

This is my template file:

```
<div id="app-main" class="app-main full-height"
   [ngClass]="{'fixed-header' : AppConfig.fixedHeader,
               'nav-collapsed' : AppConfig.navCollapsed,
               'nav-behind' : AppConfig.navBehind,
               'layout-boxed' : AppConfig.layoutBoxed,
               'theme-gray' : AppConfig.theme == 'gray',
               'theme-dark' : AppConfig.theme == 'dark',
               'sidebar-sm' : AppConfig.sidebarWidth == 'small',
               'sidebar-lg' : AppConfig.sidebarWidth == 'large'}">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me how can i store the current selected value in the browser storage?

Thanks

Comment: try: `localStorage.setItem('light-theme', 'your_awesome theme')`

Answer (score 0):

You can create on item only also. 
`localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', 'light');` // default Value.
Whenever you do change theme value, update localStorage data.